# Can I / Should I serialize a constant variable in a C# class?

Tags: c#, serialization

I am implementing the `ISerializable` interface for my class.

I have a constant variable in the class like:

```
public const decimal Cost = 3.2M
```

When I implement the `GetObjectData` method, can I / should I serial this variable?

Comment: What would be the point of doing so?

Comment: A constant variable is an oxymoron.

Comment: BoltClock is correct; that's not a *variable* in the first place. Variables are so-called because they vary.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> When I implement the GetObjectData method, can I / should I serial this variable?

Absolutely not.

Even if you *did* write it out, it's not like you could change the value of the constant when you read it back in again.

More generally, you shouldn't serialize *static* fields at all (and `const` implies `static`). Anything static is not part of the state of an *instance*, and it's the data within the instance that you're trying to serialize.

Answer (score 4):

Will it ever change? Presumably not (it can't). Then why would you bother serializing it? You couldn't even deserialize it again if you wanted to, but even if you could, it would always have the same value in it.

Answer (score 3):

Why should you? The value will never change unless you change your code.

Personally, I only serialize public properties, so constants would not be included.

Answer (score 3):

Serializing and deserializing a value is only useful if it is something that will change between object instances.  Hence serializing a `const` value doesn't make sense because it won't change.  If you do expect the value to change in the future then it probably shouldn't be `const`

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in serializing the constant as you will already know the value when you deserialize anyway as it never changes.

From http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/506109-static-fields-serialization:

> Serialization persists the state of a single object. Static fields are not part of the state of an object - they're effectively the state of the type.